# Crash enumerating arguments sent to method iOs

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I need to create a custom append with format method that will check if any argument is nil before appending.

```
-(NSString *)customStringByAppendingFormat:(NSString *)format,...{
    NSLog( @" here self is %@",self);
    NSString *stringToAppend;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    for (NSString *arg = format; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*)) // CRASH
    {
        if (arg == nil) {
            NSLog(@"NIL Arguments .");
            return self;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, format);
    stringToAppend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
    NSLog( @" string to append is %@",stringToAppend);
    return [self stringByAppendingString:stringToAppend];
}
```

The problem is that this crashes when I try to enumerate the arguments to check if any of them are nil...

What is the problem here? The crash is EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and the call trace shows objc_StoreStrong and objc_Retain as the crash point.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't gone over all your code, but I think that your 'if' inside your 'for' won't get called.

Your 'if' statement will only run if arg IS nil, but your 'for' loop condition is to run as long as arg IS NOT nil.
So basically if arg IS nil, the 'for' loop will just brake without executing the 'if' statement.

I am not familiar with all the functions that you use,
But my guess is that this is crashing since the 'for' loop breaks if arg is nil, but since your 'if' statement doesn't get called, your function doesn't return and continue to execute with the rest of the code.
My guess is that you are passing nil to one of the functions, after the 'for' loop, that doesn't accept nil as an argument.

Maybe try to add `if(arg != nil)` as a condition for the code after the 'for' loop.

Also try to add breakpoint and see exactly what line of code causing it to crash.

EDIT-

Still not sure about what it does, but maybe try to construct it that way:

```
-(NSString *)customStringByAppendingFormat:(NSString *)format,...{
NSLog( @" here self is %@",self);
NSString *stringToAppend;

va_list args;
va_start(args, format);
for (NSString *arg = format; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))  
{
    stringToAppend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];  
    NSLog( @" string to append is %@",stringToAppend);
    return [self stringByAppendingString:stringToAppend];
}
va_end(args);

return self;
```

}